# Powershell Switch Break Label not being executed

Tags: powershell, break

As part of a larger script I have implemented the `switch` detailed below.  The intention is that when the script is executed a user can choose to either

1. enter users to be migrated on-screen, or
2. import from a file.

If the import from file option is selected - I want to test the file is present - if not I want to break out and go back to the switch label `:choose`.   However when I select the import from file option and provide a non-existent path the script continues and does not break or return to the label.  Where am I going wrong?

```
$chooseInputMethod = @"
This script migrates one or more user accounts between two trusted domains in a forest e.g. from domain1 to domain2 (or vice versa)

Select method to specify user(s) to migrate:

1. Enter name(s) on-screen (default)
2. Import name(s) from file

Enter selection number
"@

$choosePath = @"
Enter path to file..

Notes

  - Filename: 
    If file is located in script directory ($pwd) you can enter the filename without a path e.g. users.txt

  - No quotation marks: 
    DO NOT put any quotes around the path even if it contains spaces e.g. e:\temp\new folder\users.txt

Enter path or filename
"@

$enterUsernames = @"
Enter username(s) seperate each with a comma e.g. test1 or test1,test2,test3`n`nEnter name(s)
"@

cls
:choose switch (Read-Host $chooseInputMethod) {
    1 { cls; $usersFromScreen = Read-Host $enterUsernames }
    2 {
        cls;
        $usersFromFile = Read-Host $choosePath;
        if (-not (Test-Path $usersFromFile -PathType Leaf)) {
            break choose
        }
    }
    default { cls; $usersFromScreen = Read-Host $enterUsernames }
}

Write-Host "hello"
```

Comment: You want a `while` loop, not a `switch`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation for `break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-6):

> In PowerShell, only loop keywords, such as Foreach, For, and While can have a label.

So, `switch`, even though it has looping capabilities, is not considered a loop in this case.

However, in this case I don't see why `break` without a label would not suffice.

Comment: Switch can have labels, and can loop.

Answer (score 1):

A break to the switch will exit it. There's only one loop (switch, which works on arrays), so there's no difference between a plain break and breaking to the switch.  You seem to want the switch inside another loop to repeat it.

```
# only runs once
:outer while (1) {
  'outer'
  while (1) {
    'inner'
    break outer
  }
}


outer
inner
```

Demo of switch with a label and looping.  The documentation isn't perfect.

```
# only runs once
:outer switch (1..10) {
  default {
    'outer'
    foreach ($i in 1..10) {
      'inner'
      break outer
    }
  }
}


outer
inner
```

Another switch demo.

```
switch (1..4) {
  { $_ % 2 } { "$_ is odd" }
  default    { "$_ is even" } 
}

1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have left Joey's answer as the correct one - as even in the examples you have shown, for a switch with a label you are breaking out of a while or a foreach loop